# How to create custom Extension Method for CRUD operation in .NET core 3.1 (without LINQ) using EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, lambda, entity-framework-core

For example I want to perform a Select operation :

```
var payerData = this.context.Payers
                .Where(x => x.Id == Data.ID)
                .Select(x => new { 
                    x.someID,
                    x.Status
                });
```

Now I want to generalize this as an extension method so that it can be used with other tables also.
Is it possible to do this? If yes, than how?

I tried to find the solution but everywhere it is given about LINQ and I want this in EF Core. And I am a beginner in .Net Core.

Comment: not clear what this statement means `I want this in EF Core`. Linq queries are transformed into SQL queries by EF Core

Comment: As @YegorAndrosov wrote in his answer, the most convenient way would be to declare a new interface and bind your classes to this one. Before doing that, think of the consequences: an interface is a contract that you should not break because then part of your logic is based on that. And you are doing it just for an extension method with a 
 `Where` and a `Select`, does it worth it?

Comment: In this scenerio, all of your entities should have ```someId``` and ```Status``` properties, or do yo want to select all the properties for all your entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to reuse query for entities that share some of the properties, then you could:

1. Create interface and apply it to every entity.
2. Create extension method and pass interface type as generic limitation.

Small demo below.
I am not sure how to help with part of your question about using LINQ since whole EF Core is built around it

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public interface TypeWithFields
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        int SomeId { get; set; }
        string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class A : TypeWithFields
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SomeId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class B : TypeWithFields
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SomeId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }

        public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
    }

    public class QueryDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SomeId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<QueryDto> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, int id)
            where T: TypeWithFields
        {
            return query.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                .Select(x => new QueryDto
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    SomeId = x.SomeId,
                    Status = x.Status
                });
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseInMemoryDatabase("memorydb");
            var dbContext = new MyContext(builder.Options);

            var queryAs = dbContext.As.Filter(1).ToList();
            var queryBs = dbContext.Bs.Filter(1).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```